# C# Script Error Object Does not Contains Definition for Property

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, contains

I am trying to create a list of members against whom I would be running comparison operation with multiple values

Here's my code

```
HashSet<string> respCodeList = new HashSet<string> { "051", "052", "055", "056", "058", "059", "061", "063", "064" };    

if (respCodeList.Contains(object.Property))
```

I am getting error in if statement :

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Property'

Found this way of doing comparison through google, but not sure why this error is coming up

Complete Code:

```
/* Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Script Component
*  Write scripts using Microsoft Visual C# 2008.
*  ScriptMain is the entry point class of the script.*/

using System;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]


public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{

    public override void PreExecute()
    {
        base.PreExecute();
        /*
          Add your code here for preprocessing or remove if not needed
        */
    }

    public override void PostExecute()
    {
        base.PostExecute();
        /*
          Add your code here for postprocessing or remove if not needed
          You can set read/write variables here, for example:
          Variables.MyIntVar = 100
        */
    }

    public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        string TermnLn = Row.TermnLn;
        string TransTypeCode = Row.TransTypeCode;
        string ReversalReason = Row.ReversalReason;
        string TransResponseCode = Row.TransResponseCode;
        string CardIssuerLn = Row.CardIssuerLn;
        string transType = Row.TransTypeCode; 
        int origTransAmount = (int)Row.origTransAmount;
        int actualTransAmount = (int)Row.actualTransAmount;


        HashSet<string> respCodeList = new HashSet<string> { "051", "052", "055", "056", "058", "059", "061", "063", "064" };



        if (TransTypeCode == "10") // IF IT IS WITHDRAWAL
        {
            if (TermnLn== "PRO1") // CHECK FOR AXIS TERMINAL
            {
                if (ReversalReason == "00") //IT IS NOT A REVERSAL
                {
                    if (respCodeList.Contains(Row.TransResponseCode))
                    {
                        Row.CashDispensed = origTransAmount/100; //cash dispense                
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (respCodeList.Contains(Row.TransResponseCode))
                    {
                        Row.CashDispensed =(actualTransAmount/100 - origTransAmount/100); //cash dispense               
                    }
                }
            }
            if (TermnLn!= "PRO1" && CardIssuerLn == "PRO1") // CHECK FOR NON AXIS TERMINAL
            {
                if (ReversalReason == "00") //IT IS NOT A REVERSAL
                {
                    if (respCodeList.Contains(Row.TransResponseCode))
                    {
                        Row.CashDispensed = origTransAmount / 100; //cash dispense non axis                 
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (respCodeList.Contains(Row.TransResponseCode))
                    {
                        Row.CashDispensed = (actualTransAmount / 100 - origTransAmount / 100); //cash dispense              
                    }
                }
            }

        }



        if (ReversalReason == "00") //IT IS NOT A REVERSAL
        {
            if (respCodeList.Contains(Row.TransResponseCode))
            {
                Row.SuccessTransOrigAmt = origTransAmount / 100; //SuccessTransOrigAmt


            }
        }


        if (ReversalReason != "00" && ReversalReason != " ")
        {
            if (transType == "0420" || transType == "0412" || transType == "0430")
            {
                if (origTransAmount == actualTransAmount)
                {
                    Row.ReversalAmount = origTransAmount / 100; //ReversalAmount
                }
                else
                {
                    Row.ReversalAmount = (actualTransAmount / 100 - origTransAmount / 100);  //ReversalAmount
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate what you are trying to compare? Your .Contains method is expecting string type.

Comment: yes I am missing the input here, this list has to be compared against values coming from this variable : string TransResponseCode = Row.TransResponseCode;

Comment: doing this respCodeList.Contains(Row.TransResponseCode) get's the error resolved .. I'll compile and check if it works functionally as well

Answer (score 0):

Just cast object as your type of objects and then try it.

```
HashSet<string> respCodeList = new HashSet<string> { "051", "052", "055", "056", "058", "059", "061", "063", "064" };    

if (respCodeList.Contains((object as YourType).Property))
```

Comment: isn't this right way of doing ? adding a reference to input object in contains  :     if (respCodeList.Contains(Row.TransResponseCode))

Comment: I am using C# script in SSIS package, this would read the input using this statement Row.ColumnName, so I want to check if all the column values coming from input are in range of HashSet then apply then trigger the condition

Comment: I have modified and added complete code in the original question

Answer (score 0):

i think it's compillation error. Because 'object' reserved [keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx).

Comment: It would be correct if C# was the language with duck typing. But it isn't.